# Are there dual-citizenship holders within the Armed Forces of United States

Tags: united-states, military, citizenship

Are there dual-citizenship holders within the Armed Forces of rank O-7 (General Officer) or higher?
What percent, if any?
Which nations, if any?

Comment: The United States does not recognize dual citizenship; US citizens are expected to owe permanent allegiance to the US. It does allow for [dual nationality](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal/travel-legal-considerations/Advice-about-Possible-Loss-of-US-Nationality-Dual-Nationality/Dual-Nationality.html). Is that what you meant?

Comment: @TedWrigley there is no meaningful distinction between dual citizenship and dual nationality.  Different countries distinguish between citizenship and nationality differently.  Both terms apply to someone who has citizenship or nationality of two countries.

Comment: @phoog: The first paragraph of the link I gave implies that 'citizen' and 'national' are used differentially by the US government, so...

Comment: @TedWrigley they have different meaning in US law with respect to US nationality and citizenship. If you want to be strict about it then someone who is a national but not a citizen of the US can only be a dual national, and someone who is a citizen of the US but a non-citizen national of another country can only be a dual national, but this is not a particularly meaningful distinction to maintain in any context. If someone is a non-citizen national of the US and a non-national citizen of another country, what term would you use then? In practice, dual citizen and dual national are synonyms.

Comment: Voting not to close - This question is asking about a Government policy and Po.SE can answer that factually.

Answer (score 2):

**Since 2011, no**.

In 2011, the US Army issued a [personnel regulation](https://www.cascadia.com/us-army-bars-dual-us-citizens-from-most-jobs/) in which the Army announced that dual citizens of the United States and another country are not permitted to enlist in the Army, Army Reserve, or Army National Guard into jobs that require a security clearance. [Not every position requires security clearance](https://news.clearancejobs.com/2022/12/22/understanding-the-military-security-clearance-process/), a cook may not need it, but you ask about the officers that must have it.

Comment: Unless they already have a security clearance.  Dual nationality is not an absolute bar to a security clearance: https://news.clearancejobs.com/2017/05/24/new-dual-citizenship-guideline-security-clearance-eligibility/

Comment: Furthermore, the policy that changed in 2011 was changed again in 2016: https://armypubs.army.mil/epubs/DR_pubs/DR_a/ARN6642-AR_601-210-001-WEB-1.pdf

Comment: That regulation links to [AR 380-67](https://armypubs.army.mil/epubs/DR_pubs/DR_a/pdf/web/r380_67.pdf), Section II 2-4 lists dual citizenship as a factor to consider when making a determination of a reasonable basis to doubt someone's loyalty, but it's not an absolute ban.

Answer (score 2):

The United States does not recognize dual citizenship. As far as the US government, including the military, is concerned you are a US citizen, a US resident (green card holder), or a foreign national.

There is a program for US residents to fast track their citizenship by joining the military.

while I am not aware of any recent cases, there were American citizens that join foreign militaries in both WWI and WWII, usually French, British, or in the case of the fly tigers in WWII Chinese.

The closest you will come to dual citizenship is an acknowledgement that other countries may also consider you to be a citizen.

While she was not in the military, I was, my wife became a US resident and later a US citizen, but she did not turn in her foreign passport, so that country still considered her a citizen. She never use that passport and it expired long ago, but she was not required by the USA or by the country that issued it to turn it in.

Comment: Whatever the US government may or may not say about anyone's citizenship and the fact that the US government does not treat its citizens with dual citizenship any differently from those who don't have dual citizenship don't answer the question of whether there are dual citizens in the US military.  The United States "not recognizing" dual citizenship is also an overstatement of their position.  For example, they recognize that US citizens who are dual citizens may use their non-US passport to enter other countries.

Comment: I am surprised that your wife didn't turn in the old passport of her origin. Mine was cut a corner that rendered it useless. However, I was able to get a new one as I was still considered a citizen of my original state.

Comment: My daughter has US, German and UK citizenship, all acquired through birth (don't ask about taxes :-S). The US has no problems issuing her a new passport on a regular basis. The rules are different when you *acquire* US citizenship later in life.

Comment: The first paragraph could be improved by mentioning U.S. nationals who are passport holding non-citizens, such as people in American Samoa.